# Calculated column from period

Tags: calculated-column

My sheet contais 3 columns - date, time period (choices: one yer period, two years period and half year period) and I would like to create rule for the third column which suppose to calculate the remaining time period to the next action (event, period).

For example: First column: 21.4.2021 - Second column: one year period - Third column: I would like to have here how many months left since next period (action event) - so for example next month (21.5.2021) I should see here 11 months left.

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Calculated columns are only going to be calculated at creation/modification so **showing remaining time at display isn't possible with calculated columns**.

If you are on SharePoint Online or SharePoint 2019 using the modern experience you can use Column Formatting to do this using the `@now` placeholder.

If you are using the classic experience or in a previous version of On-Premises SharePoint you can do this with XSLT or JSLink.

Without knowing your environment it's harder to give more detailed recommendations. Feel free to update your question with that information so we can go a little further.